# Random answers w/ 4 lines & Random questions *JAVA*

Tags: java, android

My current code:

```
TextView question; 
private int qType = -1;  
private int asked = 0;

private void QBegin() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    Random random = new Random();
    int qType = random.nextInt(5);
    switch(qType){
    case 0:
        question.setText("Question 1");
        break;
    case 1:
        question.setText("Q2");
        break;
    case 2:
        question.setText("Q3");
        break;
    case 3:
        question.setText("Q4");
        break;
    case 4:
        question.setText("Q5");
        break;
    }
    asked++;

    //intList.add(qType);
    getAnswers(qType);
    /*if(intList.contains(qType) && asked <= 5){
        QBegin();
    } else {
        answerCounter.setText("Congratulations!!! Your score : "+correct);
    }*/
}

private int answer;

private void getAnswers(int Type) {
    Random random = new Random();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(Type){
    case 1:
        if(random.nextInt(4) == 0){
            answer = 1;
            answer1.setText("относительно низкая температура шлаков");
            answer2.setText("сложность в управлении");
            answer3.setText("малая производительность");
            answer4.setText("нету выделения энергии непосредственно в загрузке");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 1){
            answer = 2;
            answer1.setText("сложность в управлении");
            answer2.setText("относительно низкая температура шлаков");
            answer3.setText("малая производительность");
            answer4.setText("нету выделения энергии непосредственно в загрузке");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 2){
            answer = 3;
            answer1.setText("сложность в управлении");
            answer2.setText("малая производительность");
            answer3.setText("относительно низкая температура шлаков");
            answer4.setText("нету выделения энергии непосредственно в загрузке");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 3){
            answer = 4;
            answer1.setText("сложность в управлении");
            answer2.setText("малая производительность");
            answer3.setText("нету выделения энергии непосредственно в загрузке");
            answer4.setText("относительно низкая температура шлаков");

        }

        break;

    case 2:
        if(random.nextInt(4) == 0){
            answer = 1;
            answer1.setText("закрытые - плавка под слоем шихты");
            answer2.setText("открытые - плавка на воздухе");
            answer3.setText("вакуумные - плавка в вакууме");
            answer4.setText("компрессорные - плавка под избыточным давлением");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 1){
            answer = 2;
            answer1.setText("открытые - плавка на воздухе");
            answer2.setText("закрытые - плавка под слоем шихты");
            answer3.setText("вакуумные - плавка в вакууме");
            answer4.setText("компрессорные - плавка под избыточным давлением");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 2){
            answer = 3;
            answer1.setText("открытые - плавка на воздухе");
            answer2.setText("вакуумные - плавка в вакууме");
            answer3.setText("закрытые - плавка под слоем шихты");
            answer4.setText("компрессорные - плавка под избыточным давлением");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 3){
            answer = 4;
            answer1.setText("открытые - плавка на воздухе");
            answer2.setText("вакуумные - плавка в вакууме");
            answer3.setText("компрессорные - плавка под избыточным давлением");
            answer4.setText("закрытые - плавка под слоем шихты");

        }

        break;

    case 3:
        if(random.nextInt(4) == 0){
            answer = 1;
            answer1.setText("в которой тепло выделяется в результате прохождения тока через проводники с активным сопротивлением");
            answer2.setText("в которой используеться активное сопротивление в качестве шихты");
            answer3.setText("в которой тепло не передаеться тепло излучением");
            answer4.setText("в которой которая делиться на компрессорную печь с активным сопротивлением");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 1){
            answer = 2;
            answer1.setText("в которой используеться активное сопротивление в качестве шихты");
            answer2.setText("в которой тепло выделяется в результате прохождения тока через проводники с активным сопротивлением");
            answer3.setText("в которой используеться активное сопротивление в качестве шихты");
            answer4.setText("в которой которая делиться на компрессорную печь с активным сопротивлением");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 2){
            answer = 3;
            answer1.setText("в которой используеться активное сопротивление в качестве шихты");
            answer2.setText("в которой используеться активное сопротивление в качестве шихты");
            answer3.setText("в которой тепло выделяется в результате прохождения тока через проводники с активным сопротивлением");
            answer4.setText("в которой которая делиться на компрессорную печь с активным сопротивлением");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 3){
            answer = 4;
            answer1.setText("в которой используеться активное сопротивление в качестве шихты");
            answer2.setText("в которой используеться активное сопротивление в качестве шихты");
            answer3.setText("в которой которая делиться на компрессорную печь с активным сопротивлением");
            answer4.setText("в которой тепло выделяется в результате прохождения тока через проводники с активным сопротивлением");

        }

        break;

    case 4:
        if(random.nextInt(4) == 0){
            answer = 1;
            answer1.setText("Correct");
            answer2.setText("Incorrect");
            answer3.setText("Incorrect");
            answer4.setText("Incorrect");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 1){
            answer = 2;
            answer1.setText("Inorrect");
            answer2.setText("Correct");
            answer3.setText("Incorrect");
            answer4.setText("Incorrect");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 2){
            answer = 3;
            answer1.setText("Inorrect");
            answer2.setText("Incorrect");
            answer3.setText("Correct");
            answer4.setText("Incorrect");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 3){
            answer = 4;
            answer1.setText("Inorrect");
            answer2.setText("Incorrect");
            answer3.setText("Incorrect");
            answer4.setText("Correct");

        }

        break;

    case 5:
        if(random.nextInt(4) == 0){
            answer = 1;
            answer1.setText("Correct");
            answer2.setText("Incorrect");
            answer3.setText("Incorrect");
            answer4.setText("Incorrect");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 1){
            answer = 2;
            answer1.setText("Inorrect");
            answer2.setText("Correct");
            answer3.setText("Incorrect");
            answer4.setText("Incorrect");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 2){
            answer = 3;
            answer1.setText("Inorrect");
            answer2.setText("Incorrect");
            answer3.setText("Correct");
            answer4.setText("Incorrect");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 3){
            answer = 4;
            answer1.setText("Inorrect");
            answer2.setText("Incorrect");
            answer3.setText("Incorrect");
            answer4.setText("Correct");

        }

        break;

    }
}
```

- I wan't to have random questions with their own random answers, that'll appear randomly on one of 4 lines, e.g :

Question 1.

'Correct asnwer'

'Incorrect answer 1'

'Incorrect answer 3'

'Incorrect answer 2'

*I click again, and same question appears, but this time..*

Question 1.

'Incorrect answer 2'

'Incorrect answer 3'

'Incorrect answer 1'

'Correct answer'

Can somebody create a simple program for me?
That'll randomly generate questions, and pick 4 answers for one of the questions, also make the questions appear randomly on 1 of 4 lines, as shown ^

P.S.
Ignore the odd language!

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Please do so. For formatting help, please see the help pages: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: This isn't a 'do-my-code-for-me' site. (Do they even exist?!) If you post some code that you tried, then by all means we'll try and make it work.

Comment: Basicly, I wan't my code to be shortened & I wan't it to be more efficient, i.o. easy to edit or/and add another question. I'm sorry if I'm asking too much! I hope I'm not.

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't hard code questions this way. Its going to make your code very difficult to read, fix, and expand.

You need to create a centralized list of questions and answers that your app can read from. You can create the questions and answers using an array XML file like this: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/values/arrays.html   Or you can create an SQLite DB that contains the questions and answers: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

These 2 ways aren't the only ways to do it, but they are simple and easy to do.

Comment: Not quite what I had in mind, I just want my code to be shortened, that's all pretty much.